# Java Calendar set time

Tags: java, calendar

I am trying to pass a specific time (for example 12:00) in my constructor. So for I've got two classes:

```
plan = new ArrayList<Plan>(); 
plan.add(new Plan(Plan1, Calendar.getInstance());
```

and the second class with constructor:

```
public class Plan
{
    private String plan;
    private Calendar startTime;


    public StudyBlock(String plan, Calendar startTime)
    {
        this.plan = plan;
        this.startTime = startTime;
    }
```

Comment: Is there a question in there somewhere?

Comment: Set the time on the calendar before passing it....

Comment: How to pass 12:00 instead of 
plan.add(new Plan("Plan1", Calendar.getInstance());
Calendar.getInstance() shoud be changed with something else?

Comment: You call [methods on Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) to set the time/date.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Calendar#set(int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set%28int,%20int%29)

```
plan = new ArrayList<Plan>(); 
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
plan.add(new Plan(Plan1, cal);
```

However if you are doing this for multiple `Plan`s then you will be modifying the same `Calendar` instance each time. So I suggest you pass a `Date` and instead call [`Calendar#getTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTime%28%29)

Comment: Well, when I try to print my plan list it gives me a lot of calendar stuffs. I want to pass only the number 12 obviously it passes: time=?,areFieldsSet=false,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Europe/Helsinki.. and so on